# MVC form submission need query string with %20 not with '+'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vue.js, axios

I have a search input type in my form. When the form is submitted, the page reloads with query params with +

So if I search for `abc def` the query param becomes `?q=abc+def` the url becomes `https://localhost:44300/Search?q=abc+def`

Now this is sent to the webapi as an api call. so then on server side I am replacing the `+` with space then performing the search on the controller. Now when I search for `abc def+efg` it becomes `abc+def%2Bdef`

```
request.Query = request.Query.Replace('+', ' ');
request.Query = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(request.Query);
```

So on server side I am first replacing the param's `+`s with a space character then decoding it and finally I get `abc def+efg` on the controller which is what I was looking for.

All this could be avoided if on the form submission the url was encoded. so if from beginning the query param was `?q=abc%20def%2Befg` I would just need to decode it.

How to do that?

*Edit*

The page renders first, then a vue component gets the query parameter, and makes a call to api controller with axios. `/api/search`

```
const searchQuery = this.$router.getQueryParam('q');

this.queryParams.query = searchQuery ? searchQuery : null;

return axios.get(`/api/search`, {
  params: queryParams,
});
```

Comment: If you `q` is a argument in your api method, it should get decoded automatically. `abc+def` = `abc def` after binding.

Comment: it is not getting decoded automatically. The call is being made from a vue component through axios. Maybe that has something to do with this.

Comment: _"I would just need to decode it"_ - have you tried? It will decode `foo+bar` into space `foo bar`

Comment: I wouldn't have asked here if it was decoding. The bug was verified and I saw in my debugger that the query while sending to lucene had the +

Comment: _"when I search for abc def+efg"_. Then the `+` is in fact part of the user's query. If you don't want to deal with it, sanitize your inputs.

Comment: yeah that is the problem. There are `+` as a part of user's query and `+` added by mvc

Comment: No it is not "added by MVC". It's decoded for you because _that is in fact part of the raw query_ an end user provided. That's what you entered in the input field right? The client will send it then (unless you do something about it). Both sides of this equation are doing exactly what they should.

Comment: The search I perfomed was `abc def+efg` I submit the form. Page reloads. with `q?=abc+def%2Befg` so this is added by mvc

Comment: No, MVC is saving you (from possible script exploits, etc.) by `encoding` that data you are echoing in some view. You can render/display raw at your own risk.

Comment: Post your webapi method sig. Where exactly in the pipeline are you determining the parameter `q` contains `abc+def`?

Comment: If you see in my question I put the url of the page after I search. which is `https://localhost:44300/Search?q=abc+def%2Befg` then I am getting it on  Vue TypeScript using `this.$router.getQueryParam('q');` then sending it

Comment: @mxmissile It wouldn't matter because both client (js/vue/typescript) and server (web api) are properly doing their end of encode/decode exchange. What the OP needs to do is sanitize user provided data on both ends depending on OP use cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you were submitting a `form`, the urleconding would be automatically applied.  Since you are getting and sending the search query without form submission, just apply a javascript function to encode that fetched value:

```
this.queryParams.query = searchQuery ? encodeURI(searchQuery): null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

Uri.EscapeUriString(request.Query)